# Sorting from a file with structures

Tags: c, file, sorting, struct

I joined a computer science course not too long ago, for the most parts ive been doing well on my own but got this assignment earlier yesterday but i cant properly form any solutions to it on my own and from what ive searched online i cant make much sense of it.

"From the list below, sort these clients alphabetically based on their last name and if they match sort by first name."

Im not used to a format in this way so would anyone know of a way to sort something of this nature, i only have the very starting of the code and it isnt much if im honest. Not even certain if im going at it correctly either by using structs but i assumed i was on the right track with that. I have added a link for how the file appears.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh4wZ.png  Thanks in advance for the assistance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct  Clients{
    char fname[50];
    char lname[50];
    int id;
    char address[100]
}check;

int main(){
    FILE *fptr;
    file = fopen("Clients.txt", "r");

    fclose(fptr);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways would be to make use of an existing sorting function and algorithm, for example you could use `qsort`.

That function takes an array of values, so you would need to store everything in an array of your structs. I recommend you to rename it to `struct Client` because every struct will contain the information of a single client.

You then need to define a function that returns -1, 0 or 1 depending on which value is greater. This function needs to match the signature `int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)` that the `qsort` function takes.

For example:

```
int clientcmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    struct Client *c1 = p1;
    struct Client *c2 = p2;
    int cmp;

    cmp = strcasecmp(c1->lname, c2->lname);

    if (cmp != 0) {      // last names are different, ok
        return cmp;
    } else {             // last names are the same, so compare first name
        return strcasecmp(c1->fname, c2->fname);
    }
}
```

Now you just need to read your data into an array of structs, and call `qsort`:

```
qsort(the_array, num_of_elements, sizeof(struct Client), clientcmp);
```